# Revert to default scale when seed changed?

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

So this is the problem. This is the node network I have (simplified). it just takes random list from objects and should change the scale to zero when value is animated. It works but, for instance if the animated scale gets to 0 and after that I want to change the seed of the random selection, those scaled down do not go back to scale 1, but stay scaled down, thus the effect is added. Any clue how to get them back to initial scale? Thanx in advance.

[image: node network screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach doesn't explicitly set the scale of all objects, some of which might have been scaled to zero at some point, so their scale never reset.

To fix that, generate a list that define the state of each object, then use that list to control the scale of objects in whichever way you want. It is clear to me that you want to control how many objects gets scaled to zero, so to implement that, we are going to generate a list that has a certain number of zeros, with ones for the rest of the list, such list can be generated using the *Fill List* node. To make sure it is randomized, we can shuffle it or shuffle the object list itself as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Thank you very much Omar! It is such an elegant solution !

Comment: Omar, one more related question: Is there any way to now exclude those objects with scale of 0 ( or less than one) from the new list of objects? I cant find a way to substract the objects with less than 1 scale from the initial group. The intent to have another operation on the remaining objects with scale of 1. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @chaba You can use the *Mask* node on the object list using the output of the fill list as the mask input.

Answer (score 0):

when you change the seed you choose some other objects to scale. this means that you lose the scaled objects. you should store them and clear their scale when you change the seed.

in addition you can make some kind of *'Callback'* using animation nodes. the approach is as follows:

store a custom property in your objects. call that `SeedForSelection`. in the steps after random nodes check if the `SeedForSelection` is the same as stored on the object; if not delete the animation keys ,clear their scale and clear their `SeedForSelection` property. after that store new seed as `SeedForSelection` in selected objects.